# Passing dynamic parameters to a parameterized Moose role

Tags: perl, moose

I want to consume the `MooseX::Storage` parameterized role, but I also want to allow parameters to be supplied through the constructor. Here is the "static" version which works as expected:

```perl
package Note;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MooseX::StrictConstructor;
use MooseX::Storage;

has title   => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
has body    => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');

with Storage(format => 'JSON', io => 'File');

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

## make a new note and store it
my $note = Note->new(title => 'Note 1');
$note->body("Here is the note");
$note->store($note->title . ".json");

## load the stored note
undef $note;
$note = Note->load("Note 1.json");
say $note->body;
```

But I want to make the Storage options dynamic. I thought of using a trait as described in [MooseX::Traits](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Traits), something like this:

```perl
package Note;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MooseX::StrictConstructor;

has title   => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
has body    => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');

with 'MooseX::Traits';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use MooseX::Storage;

## make a new note; set the storage format dynamically
my $note = Note->with_traits(Storage => {format => 'JSON', io => 'File'})->new(title => 'Note 1');
$note->body("Here is the note");
$note->store($note->title . ".json");

## load the stored note
undef $note;
$note = Note->load("Note 1.json");
say $note->body;
```

But I get an error:

```
Can't locate Storage.pm in @INC
```

I've tried to `use MooseX::Storage` in both classes, etc. I've looked at `meta->apply` and `apply_all_roles`, but neither of those seems to play well with parameterized roles.

There's something I'm not grasping about parameterized roles. I'm wondering if I should wrap the parameterized role in a non-parameterized role (e.g., `StorageWithJSONFile`) and use that a trait. Would that be a good approach?

What's an appropriate way to set the parameters of this role during object construction? Or is there a better way to give an object a parameterized role?

**Edit:** I've learned that the `Storage()` function that `MooseX::Storage` exports *returns* a list of roles when it is invoked. This cleared up a few thing for me, so I try this:

```perl
package Note;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MooseX::StrictConstructor;
use MooseX::Storage;
use Moose::Util 'apply_all_roles';

has title   => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
has body    => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');
has storage => (is => 'ro', isa => 'HashRef[Str]');

sub BUILD {
    my ($self) = @_;
    apply_all_roles($self, Storage(%{$self->storage}));
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main;
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

## make a new note and store it: this works!
my $note = Note->new(title => 'Note 1', storage => {format => 'JSON', io => 'File'});
$note->body("Here is the note");
$note->store($note->title . ".json");

## load the stored note: this does not work: Can't locate object method "load" via package "Note" at test4.pl line 32.
undef $note;
$note = Note->load("Note 1.json");  ## where are the roles?
say $note->body;
```

The contents of `Note 1.json`:

```js
{"__CLASS__":"Moose::Meta::Class::__ANON__::SERIAL::2","body":"Here is the note","storage":{"format":"JSON","io":"File"},"title":"Note 1"}
```

I seem to have a chicken-egg problem: `load()` applies to the class after `BUILD` runs; `BUILD` won't run until `load()` is called.

I think what I need is a new class with the role composed in. I may be overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new role (`JSONFiler`) that composes the Storage behaviors, then apply that role dynamically using `with_traits`:

```perl
package Note;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use MooseX::StrictConstructor;

has title   => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
has body    => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');

with 'MooseX::Traits';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package JSONFiler;
use Moose::Role;
use MooseX::Storage;

with Storage(format => 'JSON', io => 'File');

package main;
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

## create a new Note class with the Storage traits
my $note_class = Note->with_traits('JSONFiler');

## make a new note and store it
my $note = $note_class->new(title => 'Note 1');
$note->body("Here is the note");
$note->store($note->title . ".json");

## load the stored note
undef $note;
$note = $note_class->load("Note 1.json");
say $note->body;
```

Comment: If you can't change the class (i.e., 'Note') to add `MooseX::Traits`, you can get the same effect by composing the new class using `Moose::Util qw(with_traits)` and `my $note_class = with_traits(Note => 'JSONFiler');`